# DirectX Drawing Over TEdit Controls

Tags: delphi, directx

Since we upgrade to Windows 8, our TEdit boxes that are drawn in Delphi appear to be being painted over by the main DirectX surface

Here is an example of the TEdit options.

```
EdId := TEdit.Create(FrmMain.Owner);
with EdId do begin
  Parent := FrmMain;
  Color := clBlack;
  Font.Color := clWhite; 
  Font.Size := 10;
  MaxLength := 20;
  BorderStyle := bsNone; 
  OnKeyPress := EdLoginIdKeyPress; 
  Visible := FALSE;
  Tag := 10;
  DoubleBuffered := true;
end;
```

Its parent is the main form in the application, also the DXDraws parent is the same, I have tried a few hooks and a bunch of options but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that you can expect the edit controls to appear on top of the dx surface?

Comment: Before they did, only in Windows 8 and 8.1 they are rendering below the surface.

Comment: That may just have been chance